# Conformal mapping - Joukowsky Transformation

Tags: conformal-geometry

Joukowsky Transformation is: $w=z+\frac{1}{z}$
I have been asked about injectiveness of the image with respect to the area bounded inside a circle around the origin with radius $r$ for different values of $r$.

I know that the transformation $\frac{1}{z}$ preserves shapes. And I know that the Joukowsky Transformation transforms circles to ellipses. And for $r=1$ we get a staight line... But I can't figure it out whether  it preserves shapes. Is an ellipses can be seen as a circle? And the straight line - as a circle with infinite radius?

Thanks for help...

Comment: Are you just looking to find where the map $w(z)=z+\frac{1}{z}$ is injective?

Comment: yes. I thunk so. Is it true that for any r the transformation is injective? Or only for r=1?

Comment: The map is always injective on circles $|z|=r$ for $r\neq1$. To check injectivity, I'd recommend looking at solutions to $w(z_1)=w(z_2)$.

Comment: I don't understand it. how is the map injective on circles |z|=r for r≠1? It maps the circle into ellipses that can never get a=b (the radii of the allipse) and for r=1 we get a segment from -2 to 2. So how is it a circle?

Comment: "Injective" means that it maps distinct points on the circle to distinct points on the ellipse ... which it does. It doesn't mean that it maps circles to circles.

Answer (score 2):

The Joukowsky transform is injective on every circle of radius $r \neq 1$. However, when $r\neq 1$, $w$ maps the circle of radius $r$ and the circle of radius $1/r$ to the same ellipse, because we can easily check that $w(z) = w(1/z)$. This identity also shows you that $w$ fails to be injective on the unit circle. In particular, the unit circle gets sent to the interval $[-2,2]$, because if $|z|=1$ then $w(z) = z + \overline{z} = 2\text{Re}~z = 2\cos(\arg z)$. Other than these cases, circles of different radii get mapped to different ellipses. So $w$ is injective as a map on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ (where $\mathbb{D}$ denotes the unit disc), and also as a map on $\mathbb{D}\setminus \{0\}$, and therefore also conformal onto the image. In both cases the image is $\mathbb{C}\setminus[-2,2]$. If we were to restrict the domain a little more, say $\mathbb{C}\setminus \alpha\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ for $\alpha>1$ or $\beta\overline{\mathbb{D}}\setminus 0$ for $\beta<1$, then $w$ would be a conformal mapping of the domain onto the exterior of an ellipse.